# unrecognized option using apache commons cli

Tags: spring-boot, command-line, apache-commons-cli

the section of  code:

```
 Options options = new Options();
        options.addOption("h", "help", false, "prints the help content");
        options.addOption("f", "fileType", true, "file type");
        options.addOption("u", "url", true, "url");
        options.addOption("d", "validDate", true, "valid date");

        LoadReferenceFileRequest request=new LoadReferenceFileRequest();
        LoadReferenceFileResponse response=new LoadReferenceFileResponse();

       try{
          //Etape 2: Analyse de la ligne de commande
          CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
          CommandLine commandLine = parser.parse(options, args);

          if(commandLine.hasOption("f") && commandLine.hasOption("u") && commandLine.hasOption("d")) {
          String fileType = commandLine.getOptionValue('f');
          request.setFileType(fileType);

          String url = commandLine.getOptionValue('u');
          request.setUrl(url);

          String validDate = commandLine.getOptionValue('d');
          request.setValidDate(validDate);

          loadReferenceFileClientService.validateRequest(request,response);
          loadReferenceFileClientService.invokeInternal(request,response);

      }else {
             HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
             formatter.printHelp( "App" , options );
             System.exit(1);

   }
```

Error description and  command  used to execute the code :

> java -classpath MyClassPath -f .xml -usr/local/data/osmiumspa/ref/channel.xml -d 20180905
>   The error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized format specifier [n]
    ERROR StatusLogger Unrecognized conversion specifier [n] starting at position 56 in conversion pattern.
    %d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n%d [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%nError while parsing the command line: Unrecognized option: -f
```

Comment: please add the code where you have defined the `Options`.

Comment: it's done i add it

Comment: I don't see any issue in configuration. It works for me. Note that the path argument needs to have '-u' before the value: `-f .xml -u usr/local/data/osmiumspa/ref/channel.xml -d 20180905`.

Comment: that for also, yes we need to call argument with her string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue seems to be at `CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();`

use `CommandLineParser parser = new GnuParser();` which would resolve this issue